# Exceptions by DataContext

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, exception, datacontext, submitchanges

I've been doing some searching on the internet, but I can't seem to find the awnser. What exceptions can a DataContext throw? Or to be more specific, what exceptions does the DataContext.SubmitChanges() method throw?

**EDIT**
For reference, here a List of possible known exceptions that could be thrown by the L2S DataContext:

- SqlException
- ChangeConflictException
- DuplicateKeyException
- ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException
- OutOfMemoryException (when not correctly disposing the DataContext)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're right, MSDN is not a great help here. This is what I can remember from the top of my head:

- SqlException (from the ADO.NET layer)
- ChangeConflictException (L2S)
- DuplicateKeyException (L2S)
- Anything that cusomized overrides (partial void OnXXXEntity) may raise

Comment: A confirmation on this or a specific list is still welcome! Bounty ends in 30 minutes, else it's for Johannes ;]

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are underlying database exceptions (I think of type SqlClientException) when the error occurs at the database level.  There is the ChangeConflictException that it throws when it detects a concurrent change by another user.  There may be others depending on whether a value is null when it shouldn't be, that sort of thing.  A lot of the errors are unrelated to the context itself directly.

HTH.